# How to make LyX process TeX code without converting it into .lyx format?

Tags: lyx, conversion, external-files, input

When I do `\input{file}` in a `.tex` document I later import in LyX, LyX converts `file.tex` into `file.lyx` and changes `\input{file}` to `\input{file.lyx}`. But LyX doesn't do well with the TeX code it does not support natively and `\input{file.lyx}` is a rather corrupted conversion.

How can I make LyX just pass the code from `file.tex` to `pdflatex` as a part of a bigger file without LyX making any conversions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Hide" `\input` from LyX by adding to your preamble (Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble)

```
\let\fileinput\input
```

and then use

```
\fileinput{file}
```

in your document.